# Error in migration when add counter_cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

I added counter_cache for `adwerts` column in my `User` model.

When I run:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed migration
```

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted! NoMethodError: undefined method `limit' for nil:NilClass
```

My migration file:

```
class AddAdwertsCounterCashInUser < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    add_column :users, :adverts_count, :integer, default: 0, null: false

    User.reset_column_information
    User.all.each do |p|
      User.update p.id, adverts_count: p.adverts.length
    end
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :users, :adverts_count
  end

end
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Can you add your full error stack message? Also, it seems like the problem is not in this exact migration. Run your migrations with `--backtrace` option.

Comment: I understand. My problem in seeds.rb. Thanks for the response